# css: why is **color:red** deprecated?

Tags: html, css, colors, deprecated

in the page http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#style-colors they say that stuff like **color:red** is deprecated? but i'm sure I've seen many websites using these styles. does anyone know what's the reason for them being deprecated?

Comment: what did you part did you read that you think it's deprecated?

Comment: This doc: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/ says it's not, I think you made a small reading mistake here, that makes your question a bit wrong ;)

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: The WCAG from 11 years ago say not to use named colours, but it's now being standardised in CSS3.

Comment: not reccomended is certainly not deprecated. This question is just a bit wrong. And so are the answers.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne i thought they were deprecated because they wrote **deprecated example** in http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#style-colors

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The language in the [WCAG 10 guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#style-colors) is misleading - **named colors are not deprecated in [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#color-units) or [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4)**.

In addition, the recommendation **is not included** in the [latest WCAG Guidelines (2.0)](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#qr-visual-audio-contrast-without-color).

To my mind, the use of `depecrated` in WCAG 10 should actually be replaced with `not recommended`. Even then, the stated goal with this recommendation is to "Ensure that foreground and background color combinations provide sufficient contrast..", but using RGB does not help to meet this goal in any way.

There is no reason not to use the 16 color names defined in the CSS3 specification:

```
Color name  Hex rgb     Decimal
black   #000000     0,0,0
silver  #C0C0C0     192,192,192
gray    #808080     128,128,128
white   #FFFFFF     255,255,255
maroon  #800000     128,0,0
red         #FF0000     255,0,0
purple  #800080     128,0,128
fuchsia #FF00FF     255,0,255
green   #008000     0,128,0
lime    #00FF00     0,255,0
olive   #808000     128,128,0
yellow  #FFFF00     255,255,0
navy    #000080     0,0,128
blue    #0000FF     0,0,255
teal    #008080     0,128,128
aqua    #00FFFF     0,255,255
```

Interestingly, **orange** was available in the CSS2 specification, but is not included as one of the base colors in the CSS3 specification.

**Update** The [SVG 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/types.html#DataTypeColor) defined an additional 147 colors in 2001 - and all major browsers adopted them and implement them consistently.  These named colors have now been included in the [CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color) as "extended color keywords", so they are now *official* CSS.

Now that these named colors are official CSS, I'd say that it's definitely safe to use them and you can recommend their use to others - in practice, it's been this way for a long time.

Comment: so does it mean that anything outside of this list is not recommended?

Comment: @Pacerier - see my update above. You can definitely use the extended color names.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the CSS named colors is inconsistent between browsers. It'd be better to use `color: #F00;` as it will display the same in almost every browser, whereas `color: magenta;` may vary widely or not work at all.

Comment: heys did someone tested this? my **color:magenta** works the same in all my browsers

Comment: That's not really the point; most colors should work fine, but that doesn't mean they will. I'm sure for at least the most popular browsers it works fine.